# weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCException: Error reading the class file of interface

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

Issue occurs while deploying the Application to weblogic server in eclipse. If the  `.ear` file installed directly in weblogic server it is working fine.

Can anyone help on this. I have tried all options even verify installed jre and the  compiler configured in eclipse. All  point out to JDK  1.6

```
weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCException: Error reading the class file of interface com.ar.flextronics.ejb.session.remote.CountrySessionRemote
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.bytecodegen.RemoteBusIntfGener    ator.gener    ate(RemoteBusIntfGener    ator.java:23)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.bytecodegen.Gener    atorFactory.gener    ate(Gener    atorFactory.java:50)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.gener    ate(EJBCompiler.java:849)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:266)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:463)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:429)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.runEJBC(EJBDeployer.java:439)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileJar(EJBDeployer.java:795)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileIfNecessary(EJBDeployer.java:683)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:1254)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:442)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:518)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.utils.St    ateMachineDriver.nextSt    ate(St    ateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:47)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:649)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.utils.St    ateMachineDriver.nextSt    ate(St    ateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.applic    ation.internal.DeploymentSt    ateChecker.prepare(DeploymentSt    ateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.oper    ations.Activ    ateOper    ation.cre    ateAndPrepareContainer(Activ    ateOper    ation.java:209)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.oper    ations.Activ    ateOper    ation.doPrepare(Activ    ateOper    ation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.oper    ations.AbstractOper    ation.prepare(AbstractOper    ation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDisp    atcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDisp    atcher.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Class not found
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init    (Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.bytecodegen.RemoteBusIntfClassAdapter.getReader(RemoteBusIntfClassAdapter.java:38)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.bytecodegen.RemoteBusIntfClassAdapter.getRBIBytes(RemoteBusIntfClassAdapter.java:26)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.bytecodegen.RemoteBusIntfGener    ator.gener    ate(RemoteBusIntfGener    ator.java:20)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it occurring due to missing dependencies or due to incompatible java version? Since  I thought this occurs, due to incompatible version issue and thus the session classes are not getting generated. I have verified the jdk version  I been using in the workspace and clean the server and tries to re-deploy the project.? I am quite new to this, I just don't need a solution to resolve this, rather can you please help me how to trace such issues in WebLogic and resolve the issue. I revisited the domain/lib dir ...but it has all the jar needed for the project.Please help